# How can I find the LDAP server in the DNS with Indy?

Tags: delphi, dns, ldap, indy, freepascal

With the `nslookup` command (on Windows) or the `host` command on Linux, a computer can query the DNS for a LDAP server (see https://serverfault.com/questions/153526/how-can-i-find-the-ldap-server-in-the-dns-on-windows).

Is it possible to do these queries with the Indy DNS resolver component?

```
nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME
```

or

```
host -t srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy :

```
program SO18309621;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  IdDNSResolver,
  SysUtils;

var
  Dns : TIdDNSResolver;
  Rec : TResultRecord;
  Srv : TSRVRecord;
  Index : Integer;
begin
  try
    Dns := TIdDNSResolver.Create;
    try
      Dns.Host := 'mydnsserver.mydomain';
      Dns.QueryType := [qtService];
      Dns.Resolve('_ldap._tcp.mydomain');
      for Index := 0 to Dns.QueryResult.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Rec := Dns.QueryResult[Index];
        if Rec is TSRVRecord then
        begin
          Srv := TSRVRecord(Rec);
          Writeln('Target=', Srv.Target, ', Port=', Srv.Port, ', Priority=', Srv.Priority, ', Weight=', Srv.Weight);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Dns.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Just my curiosity, from what is coming the program name SO18309621;?

Comment: Actually David Heffernan started doing this (naming the project with the SO post id), I am just a copycat :).